# Proving that $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$ are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How can I show that $\mathbb{Z}_2$$\times$ $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and  $\mathbb{Z}_4$ are not isomorphic?

I don't even know how to start

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6):

**Hint.** A group isomorphism respects the order of the elements. Is there an element of order $4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: All elements of  $\mathbb{Z}_2$$\times$ $\mathbb{Z}_2$ have order 1 or 2 so is not isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

Comment: Exactly, that is what it is!

Comment: And exactly what it was (in the duplicate)!

Comment: I answered before seeing it was a duplicate... I should have thought such a question is certainly a duplicate, will do next time!